# Where to find MSOffice 2013 installer? Wine 2.0

Tags: microsoft-office, wine

After viewing this [how to install office 2013 question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879304/wine-2-0-says-it-supports-office-2013-how-do-i-actually-install-it) I am lost on where to find the Office2013Setup.x86.exe file, to install office 2013, (last step). I've dug around microsoft's download pages to no avail.

Looking for a source to dl this .exe or for someone to tell me what I'm not understanding.

Comment: you find a retail copy of it

Comment: [Download and install or reinstall Office 2013 on a PC or Office for Mac 2011](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Download-and-install-or-reinstall-Office-2013-on-a-PC-or-Office-for-Mac-2011-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: You can use https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-iso-download-tool to download Office 2013. You obviously need a license for Office 2013 which begs the question, if you have one, you should have a digital download link and/or physical media

Comment: @DavidPostill FYI: "After February 28, 2017, you can no longer download and install Office 2013 as part of your Office 365 subscription."